# How to confirming GCM bugfix in J9VM

Tags: java, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to determine if bugfix, "IV70544: CIPHERSPI CALLED ENGINEUPDATE() WHICH IS NOT SUPPORTED FOR AES/GCM" 
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IV70544
has be integrated into the current release of JDK 1.8.

The bug report states the fix will be in release "8 SR1 (8.0.1.0)" but I don't
find any clear correlating text in my JDK version information nor do I find a
list of bugfixes for the release.   Here is the version information for the 
JDK I am using.

```
java -version
java version "1.8.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build pxi3280sr3fp20-20161019_02(SR3 FP20))
IBM J9 VM (build 2.8, JRE 1.8.0 Linux x86-32 20161013_322271 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
J9VM - R28_Java8_SR3_20161013_1635_B322271
JIT  - tr.r14.java.green_20161011_125790
GC   - R28_Java8_SR3_20161013_1635_B322271
J9CL - 20161013_322271)
JCL - 20161018_01 based on Oracle jdk8u111-b14
```

Can anyone confirm if the fix is or should be present in this release?

Comment: Write a program triggering the bug on the broken JVM you have, and run it on the JVM you are curious about.  If this is crucial to you, create a "run this first" set of tests you can run as part of each new deployment.

Answer (score 0):

From the link: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IV70544

"*This APAR will be fixed in the following Java Releases:
   8    SR1       (8.0.1.0)*" ....

This means that the fix will be present in Java 8 SR 1 and all versions above this. Your Java version is higher - 8.0.3.20 - this version will contain the fix.